# Windows 10 freezes ingame

Tags: windows, windows-10, gaming

I have an old Intel HD Graphics from the second generation (i3-2100 @ 3.10GHz). When I play source engine games like Left4Dead and many others (The last one, Fallout New Vegas) the entire PC just freezes. First the sound and the keyboard stops (For example, the player keeps walking in the same direction but the keyboard freezes), and after ~2 seconds the entire PC finally freezes and I have to shut the computer down. The thing is, there are no drivers for this Intel HD Graphics for Windows 10, and when I was on Windows 8 I could play all these games without freezing (They could run quite slow with higher graphics, but PC ran ok). That is frustrating the hell out of me and I'd like to know if there's a miraculous solution apart from uninstalling everything and installing Windows 8.

Comment: If it plays for a short while and then suddenly stops then it could be overheating. Use a program like HWInfo to monitor your temperatures and see what they get up to while playing. Given your symptoms you may need to try playing in windowed mode so that you can switch to the monitoring program before it overheats. If it is overheating then you might need to look at whether you have adequate cooling available.

Answer (score -1):

i think it's overheating problem. Many CPU and GPUs are designed to be force shut-down prevent from Damaging your PC. So

1. Check your CPU cooler.
2. Change CPU cooler.
3. Check your Intel Graphic driver update.

Comment: Ad 3.: `The thing is, there are no drivers for this Intel HD Graphics for Windows 10`. Ad 2.: Why should that be necessary? If it worked before, why would it now not work? Ad 1.: What to check? (Dust, thermal paste, ...?) Also, why not check temperatures via a tool before?